# Is it possible to merge another DELETED user to my user?

Tags: support, deleted-users, merge-accounts

I know it is possible to merge two users' accounts into one of them. I read about this concept in the help center. And I should request to merge them.

But can I request a merge if one of the user accounts has been **DELETED**? I'm referring to the account for 'user10516706'.

Comment: *User deletion is irreversible!* from the Help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account. So no, you can't merge some deleted account into your existing one as that would make user deletion reversible.

Comment: Thanks, dear @rene, It is very uncomfortable for me. the merge request is just for live Stack Exchange users. the deleted ones cannot come back to life. sad

Comment: Short of putting the above message in flashing-neon letters, it couldn't have been made clearer. You're warned in the help center _and_ before you delete your account that deletion cannot be undone. This is also why there's a minimum of a 24 hour waiting period before your account is removed.

Comment: @rene Just to be 'provocative' (not my style, I know, but...) The SE 'machine' never actually 'forgets' anything so, in theory, it is *possible* to reverse an account deletion? What about those folks who have deleted their accounts 'in protest' about something and then, later, that 'something' was fixed?

Comment: @AdrianMole: The SE 'machine' does forget things. Especially data that is covered by the GDPR. For example, e-mail addresses of deleted users should be gone which means there is no way to proof that the deleted account has been owned by you. In short: Don't ever delete your account unless you want it to be gone forever.

Comment: @BDL A good point, well made! So, although "deletion" (in the context of questions/answers) *is* reversible, genuine "redaction" is not. Have I got that right?

Comment: @AdrianMole well, see the comments on [this official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307567/158100). Not sure how much begging that involves nor if that is worth the effort for [15 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1201611).

Comment: @rene I guess my 'answer' is in BDL's comment, and "GDPR" - so, let's say I delete my account: I would *expect* (and require) that all pertinent data are deleted. If I could then (somehow) restore that account (or even retrieve info therefrom), I could start litigation against SE in terms of failure to comply with the aforementioned GDPR legislation! Moral of the story: Don't delete your account unless you *really* want to delete it. :)

Comment: Dear comrade @rene, I'm the PostOwner, not **AdrianMole**, please keep calm, no one begging here, I just ask, and maybe it is my fault, I should read completely the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account). And I believe **Adrian** just wanna know why the deleted account is not reversible. And by my idea, A deleted account is not reversible maybe because of its cost for support or development team. Or maybe for the architecture of Stack Exchange, it is not reversible. Generally, it is not reversible and no one begging. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Help Center article [How do I delete my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) it is stated as the first sentence:

> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.

That same text is shown to you when you select delete account on your profile as can be seen  in the screenshot taken from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307567/158100) from [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija):

> [image]

And that dialog and its wording existed in March 2018 which is before you posted with [that previous account](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1201611) so you could have seen that text when you deleted that account.

So the official stance is: No, you cannot merge an deleted account back into an existing account because it is irreversible.

However, reading the comments on that answer from Catija it is revealed that there are known cases where users that deleted their account and later returned to the site had their older posts re-linked with their new account.

This doesn't seem a normal practice and if you run into [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) it is probably declined. But based on the anecdotal evidence in the comments I presume that if you persist in stalking Community Managers and/or support staff they might give in and re-link those 15 posts of your former account to your new account.

If you want to give that a try I suggest to send a request using the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) form and in your request link to this answer. Please let us know the outcome if you take this route.

Comment: I swear I didn't persist in stalking Community Managers and/or support staff, I just wanna know is a way to re-link that 15 posts to my primary account or not. Everything which I told about the cost of the support team or development team or other staff and architecture of the business model of Stack Exchange is not stalking, I really believe such these cases like my request are not valuable or worthy for the system to answer. By the way, do you offer me to send a re-link request? and if yes, how?

Comment: @AmerllicA the last sentence of my answer tried to explain what you can attempt to get those posts re-linked. Click the link, enter the form, submit and wait.

Comment: Thanks, dear @rene for your time, my friend **revo** told me using comrade word on Stack Overflow is not good. I just mean call you dear friend, dear dude or dear buddy, undoubtedly, I don't wanna be rude, I'm very gentle, If you got upset, I apologize.

Comment: I suggest you just stick with calling people by their chosen display name, @AmerllicA. In this case, that would be “rene”. Other terms, whether meant as endearing or not, have other connotations that make them subject to being misinterpreted.

Comment: In this case, while user10516706 did request deletion of their own account, it was actually deleted manually by a moderator before the automated deletion process had a chance to run. It was deleted as a sockpuppet. As such, I don’t think it is ever going to be recovered or merged. What would be the point? If you want to re-ask a question that your sockpuppet account had asked, please let a moderator know, so that we can merge the old question in with your new one. @AmerllicA

Comment: @CodyGray, Now I wanna to re-link my 15 posts of deleted user to my current account. and also I have new question, is it possible to re-link all of my sockpuppet accounts' posts to my current account?

Comment: You are joking now, yes?

Comment: No, that is not possible. I cannot even see what would be the point. @AmerllicA

Comment: @MartinJames, No at all, the sockpuppet accounts had some useful answers and questions which I wrote them, ok they aren't for community purpose, they were sockpuppet, but the posts are valuable.

Comment: @CodyGray, Is this impossibility come from this request illegal or it is impossible because of technical issue?